# How to construct URL from mysql values (automatic process)

Tags: php, mysql, url, tree

I have a quick question. Please look at the part of my mysql table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ID      |       PARENT      |       URL     |       NAME        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |       0           |       index   |       Home page   |
|   2       |       1           |       offer   |       Offer       |
|   3       |       2           |       map     |       Map         |
|   4       |       0           |       office  |       Office      |
|   5       |       4           |       contact |       Contact     |
```

How should I create a query, to get something like this:

```
<a href="index/offer/map/">Map</a>
```

This should be an automatic query, rather than manual construction of the url. I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: this has security threat written all over it.

Comment: so it's impossible to get such result ?

Comment: Would it be possible to alter your table schema?  Or are you stuck with this schema design?

Comment: I'm stuck with this schema design. Probably I've designed the table not properly, but it's too late for any bigger changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name as name, CONCAT(c.url, "/", b.url, "/", a.url) as url
FROM table a, table b, table c
WHERE a.parent = b.id AND b.parent = c.id
      AND a.id = 3;
```

Then just use that in your code to build the url.

You might not even need that last part of the `WHERE` clause (depending on what you want to get out of the query).

Comment: thanks, but if I don't know how deep is the last element ? Is it possible to create a query which will check it automatically and create correct path / url ?

Comment: @Jakub you might have to do that somewhere on your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Does not look very intuitive I guess:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', href, '">', label, '</a>') as a FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
CONCAT(
IF(ISNULL(t1.url), '', t1.url), 
IF(ISNULL(t2.url), '', CONCAT('/', t2.url)),
IF(ISNULL(t3.url), '', CONCAT('/', t3.url))
) AS href,
IF(ISNULL(t3.name), IF(ISNULL(t2.name), t1.name, t2.name), t3.name) as label
FROM `test`.`7679298` t1 
LEFT JOIN `test`.`7679298` t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN `test`.`7679298` t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
GROUP BY label) d;
```

Results in:

```
<a href="office/contact">Contact</a>
<a href="index/offer/map">Map</a>
```

(EDIT: replaced `CASE`by `IF`)